# Abbreviation of "interitem correlation"?

Tags: terminology, reliability, reporting

I am summing up a reliability analysis in a table. I am including Cronbach's alpha values and interitem correlations for subgroups as well as my entire sample. I have trouble fitting the headings in the table.

Is there any way to abbreviate "Interitem correlation"? Right how I am thinking about just writing 'r*' and in a footnote write: * = Interitem correlation

Is this good or bad? Any better suggestions?

Comment: As long as you explain it in the footnote you can call it what you want I think.

Comment: I could see an argument being made for $r^*$ with a footnote or $\bar{r}$ with a textual description. Another thing to note is that interitem correlation is often referred to as internal consistency. Not much shorter, but another option to consider including for clarity.